# How to embed the provisioning profile for a launch daemon on OSX?

Tags: macos, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, xpc

I am developing a Mac application which also installs a launch daemon. Both application and daemon are codesigned with different identities and different entitlements but the launch daemon refuses to start.

Looking into system logs I see these messages:

> taskgated-helper[7269]: Found 0 provisioning profiles
>
> taskgated-helper[7269]: Disallowing com.test.MyApplication[pid 7268] because no provisioning profiles found

Usually for Mac applications the provisioning profile is copied inside the bundle and available in MyApplication.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile. But I haven't found a good way to make to make the daemon find the provisioning profile at startup. The best I found was to double-click on the provisioning profile and install it on the system so it appears in System Preferences but this isn't acceptable user experience for users of this application.

How can I make a launch daemon find the provisioning profile? can I specify a path to it's location or can it be embedded in the binary(same way -sectcreate linker flag does)?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried various combinations and one of them seemed to work best for what I need. I've created a separate application with separate entitlements and provisioning profiles and resides inside MyApplication.app 's bundle and the launch daemon is a process whose only purpose is to run the service application. Pros and cons for this solution are:

- Service has it's separate set of entitlements that can vary independently from the host application **(+)**
- When the application is removed the service also goes so you need not worry about the service still being installed or unintuitive uninstall procedure **(+)**
- The launch daemon is running with elevated privileges and invokes some application at a specific location; without proper measures this is a huge security flaw. **(-)**

What I've described above is very similar to XPC services except that I need my service to run at all times, even when the main application isn't running. As opposed to XPC services which run only on demand and are killed whenever are idle for a long time.

Is there any way I could use XPC services instead and have it running at all times, not just when the consumer app performs a request?